# How to correctly use of imagettftext?

Tags: php, php-gd

I am making a form which the user is filling to create a mail signature:

generatarjeta.php

```
if(isset($_GET["suc"]) && $_GET["suc"] !="")
{ $code="";
  foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    $code.= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
  }
  $code = rtrim($code,"&");
  ?>
  <img src="imagem.php?<?php echo $code;?>">
  <script>window.history.pushState("", "", '/generatarjeta.php');</script>
  <?php exit();
}

<form method="get">
      <table>
        <tr><td><label>Sucursal</label></td><td><select name="suc">
          <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
          <?php
          $con_sucursal = mssql_query("select * from localitos where local NOT IN (3,5, 7,12, 13, 14,15,16,17,19, 20, 21, 22,23,24,25,26,27)");
          while ($res_sucursal = mssql_fetch_array($con_sucursal))
          {
            echo "<option value='$res_sucursal[0]'>$res_sucursal[1]</option>";
          }?>
        </select></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>Nombre del Trabajador: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="nombre" required="" onkeypress="return textonly(event);"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>Puesto: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="puesto" required="" onkeypress="return textonly(event);"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>Telefono: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="tel" required="" onkeypress='return solonums(event)'/>&nbsp;<label>Extension: </label><input type="text" name="ext" onkeypress='return solonums(event)'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label>correo: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="nombre.apellido"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generar"/></td><td><input type="reset"/></td></tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

imagem.php

```
//Carregar imagem
$rImg = ImageCreateFromJPEG("the_firma.jpg");
//Definir cor
$cor = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 226, 41, 34);
$cor2 = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 60, 60, 59);

$tel = "$_GET[tel] Ext. $_GET[ext]";
$correo = "$_GET[mail]@mail.x";
//Escrever nome
imagettftext($rImg,14,0,850,60,$cor,'Open Sans',$_GET["nombre"]);
//imagestring($rImg,5,850,60,urldecode($_GET["nombre"]),$cor);
//imagestring($rImg,5,850,80,urldecode($_GET["puesto"]),$cor2);
//imagestring($rImg,5,800,120,urldecode($tel),$cor2);
//imagestring($rImg,5,800,140,urldecode($correo),$cor2);
//Header e output
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($rImg,NULL,100);
```

My issue is, when I use imagestring, everything works fine, but I need to use Open Sans ttf so I tried to use imagettftext, but it "echoes" an empty result or error when loading img src and also when testing file separately it doesnt show any error.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

```
$tel = "$_GET[tel] Ext. $_GET[ext]";
$correo = "$_GET[mail]@mail.mx";
$puesto = strtoupper($_GET["puesto"]);


imagettftext($rImg, 14, 0, 780,60, $cor, 'OpenSans-Bold.ttf', $_GET['nombre']); (WORKS)
imagettftext($rImg, 8, 0, 780,80, $cor2, 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf', $puesto); (WORKS)
imagettftext($rImg,9,780,135,$cor2, 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',urldecode($_GET["tel"])); (CRASHES)
imagettftext($rImg,9,780,172,$cor2,'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',$correo);(CRASHES)
imagettftext($rImg,8,780,209,$cor2,'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',$_GET["direccion"]);(CRASHES)
imagettftext($rImg,8,780,223,$cor2,'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',$_GET["dir2"]);(CRASHES)
```

Comment: It looks correct to me. Are you sure your variables are correct? Have you tried to var_dump(urldecode($correo));?

Comment: $correo does work correctly with imagestring, not with imagettftext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), the `$fontfile` parameter needs a *path* to the font file, not its display name:

> The path to the TrueType font you wish to use.

The simplest solution is to put the .ttf file (`opensans.ttf`?) in the same folder as your script and then change your function call like so:

```
imagettftext($rImg, 14, 0, 850, 60, $cor, 'opensans.ttf', $_GET['nombre']);
```

Comment: Then the name of the ttf should be open_sans.ttf?

Comment: I don't know what the name of the file you have is.  You'll need to check this yourself.  On my system the regular font is `OpenSans-Regular.ttf`.

Comment: Well it does work as you said, but when I send a parameter with numbers it crashes maybe is my sintax I'll edit with part of your code

Comment: Is there an error message when it crashes? (Check the PHP errors log if you don't have `display_errors` enabled.)

Comment: Comment out the 'header' line so that you can see any error messages.

Comment: Done, I was missing a parameter P: ty